# How to create a virtual line which is perpendicular of my current position

Tags: android, math, gps, geometry, 2d

Here I am not an expert in math, but I would draw a line starting or at least put 2 points on both sides of my current position, taking into account the orientation of the phone.

Basically it would be:

```
                    Orientation

                         ^
                         |
X1(lat,long)<-- MycurrentPosition(lat,long)-->X2(lat,long)
```

For instance : I search to calculate X1|X2 from my current position and orientation.
X1 and X2 must be perpendicular to my current position and orientation.

The goal of this part is to make a starting line when user use a button to start recording track.

I find this algo to calculate after, if the user crossed the line :
http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/intersection-lines.html

I began to look to the vectors, but I admit I struggled to find what would be best. Not seen by comparing mathematical algorithm

If anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [great resource](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) with useful formulae and code. Your task is "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point". 
For example, if you know own position (start point) and orientation, then

```
  bearing  =  orientation +- 90 degrees
```